Embedded System Design Project - Picking Hardware and General Confusions
I’m currently working on the design of an embedded system for a robot that includes various components such as a depth camera, motors, LiDAR sensors, IMU, etc. I’m considering a modular architecture where each component is managed by separate nodes controlled by microcontrollers (e.g. STM32s), and all nodes communicate via a CAN bus. Since the robot needs to run computer vision algorithms, the plan is to have a central node that uses a microprocessor (e.g. Raspberry Pi).
I had a few questions about the architecture design for the project,

Is the aforementioned idea feasible?
What is the benefit of dividing the components into nodes and is it necessary to use separate microcontrollers for each node instead of hooking everything up to the microprocessor?
Is a CAN bus the best option for a communication protocol?

Any other general suggestions/resources would be greatly appreciated since I am very new to this. Thanks.

This is a very broad "big picture" design question, so it's all quite subjective. You need to start with gathering the specific project requirements before running off to do a system design, let alone picking components.

Is the aforementioned idea feasible?

Yes. Although Raspberry Pi isn't really suitable for industrial use. It might be suitable for the computer vision parts, but not for critical decision-making and certainly not for safety-related purposes, if that's a thing here. Moving robots are almost certainly safety-related in one way or the other. So risk assessment is another thing that needs to be carried out early on, together with the requirements gathering.
In general, it is probably wise not to re-invent the wheel but to look at pre-made products meeting your requirements. Why hack together some computer vision in Rasp Pi if there's already lots of products for that very purpose on the market?

What is the benefit of dividing the components into nodes and is it necessary to use separate microcontrollers for each node instead of hooking everything up to the microprocessor?

In general terms, modularization and decentralization is good design since it lets each module deal with it's own designated task and not concern itself with unrelated parts. So if something breaks or goes wrong, only that function will fail and not some unrelated part. The system becomes more rugged and maintainable overall. In software design we would speak of "loose coupling", but the concept is applicable to any system design. It's easier to maintain a number of less complex microcontrollers with less complex software, than a single big & very complex one.
In pure EE terms, you can and should have localized voltage regulators. It is custom to have some central "raw" machine voltage of 12VDC or 24VDC, then distribute that one and have each module implement a local voltage regulator down to 3.3V etc. This helps with EMC problems, voltage drops, ground currents etc etc. Separating supply and signals in cables is usually also the ideal, but not always practical or possible.
The down sides of modularization is more components and more connectors overall, so a bigger BoM. Some rule of thumb is that every connector in particular is a potential source of errors, so we should strive to minimize the amount of connectors in a system.

Is a CAN bus the best option for a communication protocol?

With what little information you have given, it does sound like a good option. It is a great bus overall for rugged, modular systems. But without any requirements, who can tell. The weakness of CAN is the low data transmission speed - for example you wouldn't realistically be able to transfer live video signals from some camera over CAN.
